# What is the static web site server of spring document system?

Tags: spring, document, hugo

I want a static web site server like hugo. My requirement is adding left navigation,building single html, supporting markdown. The spring document system is what I want.What server does spring use?Is it open source?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Spring documentation is done with [Asciidoctor](https://asciidoctor.org/).

The project [spring-boot-docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs) contains the documentation, look into the folder `src/docs/asciidoc/`. Github is able to render `adoc` files, so when you click on a file you will see it rendered. To view the source click on the `Raw` button on top of a file.

The project is build with `gradle`, so the various ouput formats (PDF, Single HTML, multiple HTML) are created with this build file: [build.gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs/build.gradle).

Answer (score 0):

The website https://whatcms.org/?s=spring.io%2Fprojects%2Fspring-boot tells us:

```
Web Framework: Spring  
Programming Language: Java
```

It also tells us they use Gatsby and Github Pages. This layout (with Markdown support) can be achieved with minimal effort in Hugo.